# Access one function on other file

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I would like connect the function of file home.html to file index.js. It's possible?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Port = 8080;

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(
    Port,
    () => console.log('its alive on http://localhost:' + Port)
);

var url = [];
var User = [];

app.post('/tshirt/:id', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.Request == "NovaMusica") {
    
    res.send({
        Musica: req.body.Musica, User: req.body.User
    });
        url.push(req.body.Musica);
        User.push(req.body.User);
        var testa = require('./home.html');
        testa.test(url, User)

    
    }});
```

home.html:

```
<html><head>
<script>
export function test(... args){
    $.each(url, function(index, value) {
        $('<label style="margin-top:15px;display:inline-block;margin-left: 5%;">'+url[index]+' (time)<br><br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;'+User[index]+'</label>', {
          'text': value
        }).appendTo('sendMusics');
      });
}
```

I would like connect function test of home.html to request on app.post.

It's possible? Thanks for helping me

Comment: You cannot export modules from HTML. `export` only be used in `type="module"` scripts which require you load the script content from an external file using `src`.

Comment: Why do you even want to run jquery server-side? what's wrong with it running on the client's browser?

Comment: @connexo sorry i forgot put src ...

Comment: @Samathingamajig i try 1 and 2 times to do this command on server. But return all time a error, so i decide change the code to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: **You cannot run client-side, DOM-manipulating JS on the server; it requires a browser with your page loaded to run.**

Nonetheless, here's what you'd need to do in more useful cases:

Move the script from the HTML to a file `test.js`:

```js
// test.js
function test(... args){
    $.each(url, function(index, value) {
        $('<label style="margin-top:15px;display:inline-block;margin-left: 5%;">'+url[index]+' (time)<br><br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;'+User[index]+'</label>', {
          'text': value
        }).appendTo('sendMusics');
    });
}

export { test };
```

Then inside `home.html` replace the inline script by

```
<script src="./path/to/test.js" type="module"></script>
```

So inside your `index.js` you can then `import` it (at the top of your file):

```
import { test as testa } from './path/to/test.js';
```

Comment: Hey connexo, thanks for supporting me. But i try run the project and return this error https://prnt.sc/U_NtU10Bx2pJ

Comment: Your importing code must also be a module. https://blog.logrocket.com/es-modules-in-node-today/

Comment: i remove export and import on index.js and work. Thanks